# Add an existing project to SVN Version

Tags: svn

I have downloaded Tortoise SVN. 
I have created SVN Repository by right clicking on an empty folder.
 I have an existing project and i want to add it to the newly created SVN Repository.
 So that i can checkout the project by checkout option of SVN and do the changes and can commit it.

Copy the existing project and paste it to the SVN repository folder is not working. Because when i use checkout option in some other folder the copied project is not coming.

Can somebody please help , how to add an existing project to the newly created svn repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the command line, you can add it like this:

```
cd existing/code
svn import <Link> -m "<Message>"
```

With tortoiseSVN there should also be something like import, but I do not know much about tortoiseSVN

Comment: oh, my fault. But normally create, checkout, add files, commit should work. Are you sure you commited your changes? Can you see the files in your repositary?

Comment: Thanks. When u checkout in some folder, u have to paste the project that u want to add it to the version. And add the files to the SVN version. and commit.